# Backup not taking latest position

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, ssms

We are doing a Backup / Restore with maintenance plans. Running a scheduled job for the maintenance plan to backup a database and save it to another server. The backup is being created every night and we can see it.

When we restore the backup we have another job running a script and its working for one day then stops. It seems that the script puts in a hard number for the `with file = 15` The backups keep going.

For example... position 1, 2, 3, 4..etc. The script only runs at position 2. Is there a way to get the latest position every restore?

```
USE [master]

RESTORE DATABASE [db1]
FROM  DISK = N'C:\Room\db1.bak'
WITH
  FILE = 15,
  MOVE N'db11_data' TO N'C:\room\db1.mdf',
  MOVE N'db1_log' TO N'C:\Room\db1_1.ldf',
  NOUNLOAD,
  REPLACE,
  STATS = 5

GO
```

How do we get the `With FILE = 15` to always go to the next backup position?

Is there a better way to detach a database, clear logs, and restore a database?

Comment: Have you considered using backup files with date/time stamps? This would allow an alternate solution compared to your existing process of including multiple backup sets within a single file--which the `FILE=N` is dealing with

Comment: Best practice is to always use a new file, as @AMtwo says. Otherwise it gets complicated to automate, using `RESTORE HEADERONLY` in an `EXEC`, which is very messy and brittle

Comment: In addition to above comments (with which I agree). This seems strange to me: "Is there a better way to detach a database, clear logs, and restore a database?". What is your real problem here? Are you doing some backup/restore do clear the transaction log?